# Best practice for call multiple controllers from one view at Symfony4

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony4

I have a doubt about which is the best practice in order to call multiple controller from one view.

I mean, i have the following situation:

Controller -> posts
Controller -> comments

Entity -> post
Entity -> comments

view -> \templates\posts

In order to access to both controllers from the view posts, which is the best practice?. shall i use the the controller comments as a service?. Or i must use those two entities in one controller<-> one view?.

Thanks.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think, This's about thing you want https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html